# Where should run-time unix sockets live on Linux?

Tags: linux, fhs

I have an application that creates a lot of unix sockets to interact with all the processes it spawns at run time.
I thought /run/appname would be a good place for them to live, since from what I've understood, /run should be used for information from apps that's only valid during run-time of the app.

But the I discovered

```
$ mkdir /run/appname
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/appname': Permission denied
```

So why can a normal user not create files in /run? What is it used for?
Should I just keep to /tmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put them in a subdirectory of `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` if the variable is set.  See the XDG Basedir Standard: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

If it's not set, there are a few places to consider.  Many distributions have systemd (or something) create `/run/user/<user-id>` when a user logs in, so it might be the best place to start looking if `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not set.  If that fails I fall back to putting things in `/tmp`.  You might try to create a directory within /tmp named randomly or after the username/id with your application name, `chown` it to the user of the app, set any appropriate permissions, then put sockets in there.

Answer (score 0):

/run is reserved for root/system apps.

```
1. Contact your system admin and ask him to create a socket file for you
```

or

```
2. Put into /tmp or the specific forlder in $HOME/
```

Comment: /usr is a bad idea.  User write privileges are going to be meager or likely non-existent.

Comment: And you might consider `/var/tmp/` also. But `/usr` is really a bad idea. Sometimes, it is NFS-mounted read-only!

Comment: Of course, for a user-specific application, consider something under its `$HOME`, perhaps in `$HOME/.cache/`

Comment: Or consider having some `$HOME/.appname` directory (of course replace `.appname` by something appropriate to your application).

Comment: apparently there is /run/user/$user - but when should that be used instead of just /tmp?